# If Meta exists get value and insert text into a div html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta

I have a global header that external applications include without the ability to modify.

The do have access to add a meta tag. And I want to check if they add a meta tag with title and if it exists take value and insert into an h2 empty div.

### HTML

The `meta` tag would look like this:

```
<meta name="HeadTitle" id="HeadTitle" content="This Apps Title"/>
```

Markup will look like this:

```
 <div id="optionalTitle" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4 pull-right"><h2></h2></div>
```

### JavaScript

How do I check if a meta name exists and if so, get the value and insert it into the `h2` element?

```
  if ($('#HeadTitle').length) {
    // append content to optionalTitle h2
  }
```

### Update Progress

I have it working like this

```
    if ($('#HeadTitle').length) {
            $('#optionalTitle > h2').append($('#HeadTitle').prop('content'));
     }
```

but not like this

```
     var $meta = ($('#HeadTitle'));
       if ($meta.length) {
            $('#optionalTitle > h2').append($meta.prop('content'));
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just use the [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method on the appropriate element:

```
var $meta = $('#HeadTitle');
if ($meta.length) {
    $('#optionalTitle > h2').append($meta.prop('content'));
}
```

If you wish to replace the content instead of appending, [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) would work better for you.

Comment: Please take a look at my progress. Defining `$meta` with ` $('#HeadTitle');` seems not to work. what do you think?

Comment: disregard. Its working! Jquery has to load before js code! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:
**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b3dxx66y/1//)**

```
$(function () {
    var $HeadTitle = $('meta[name="HeadTitle"]');

    if ($HeadTitle.length) {
        $("#optionalTitle h2").text($HeadTitle.attr("content"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
 if($('#HeadTitle').attr('content')){
     //your logic here
 }
```

Work for you ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This does answer their question... he said he wanted the content to exist.  The above would do it.

Answer (score 0):

In JS only you can do:

```
<!-- start head -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="HeadTitle" id="HeadTitle" content="This Apps Title"/>
<title>Document</title>
<!-- end head -->

<!-- in body -->
<h2 class="title" id="title"></h2>
<script>
var metaTitle = document.getElementById('HeadTitle'),
    title = document.getElementById('title'),
    content = metaTitle.getAttribute('content');
    if (!!content) {
        title.innerHTML = content;
    }

</script>
```

I think getAttributes is widely supported if not element.attributes has been supported since ie6 you can see an example of that use [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)